# What does the "eval()" function do in Python?

Tags: python

Please consider this code:

```
import random
name = input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")

number1 = random.randint(20,50)
number2 = random.randint(1,20)
oper = random.choice('+-*')

result = eval(str(number1)+oper+str(number2))
answer = (int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')) == result)

if answer == True:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Incorrect!')
```

What is the difference between the `answer` and `result` variables and what is the point of `eval`? What's its purpose?

Comment: Please change the title to something meaningful and fix your indentation. Please be specific about what part of the documentation of the used functions you did not understand.

Comment: Changed and I have been specific read the last line.

Comment: @PythonNooby, is this Python 2 or Python 3? For the former, `input()` already includes an implicit `eval()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The `eval` is working on the generated question, not the response.

Comment: @JamieBull, that's true, but the above is -- I believe -- still worth mentioning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed. I didn't know myself that it had changed in Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the `answer` variable is what the user enters in response to your request for `input`. It's their answer to your question. The `result` variable is the correct answer to your randomly generated question. What you want to do is check whether their `answer` is the same as the expected `result` (which is why I called that variable `correct_answer` in my answer to your previous question).

The reason for using `eval` is that it **eval**uates an expression which is passed as a string. So for example if you pass "2*3" to `eval` it will return 6.

The documentation for `eval` is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) which is always a good place to start.

Breaking down the line which is giving you trouble:

```
result = eval(str(number1)+oper+str(number2))
```

Breaks down for an example where `number1` is 4 and `number2` is 7:

```
result = eval("4*7")
```

The "4*7" is then converted by `eval` from the string "4*7" to the source code `4*7` which is then calculated out to be `28`.

I think the difficulty you're having is seeing that there is a difference between "4*7" which is a string, and `4*7` which is a code statement. What `eval` does is convert strings to statements which can then be executed as code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how will line 6 give us the actual answer , how does line 6 work ?

Comment: Thank you , The answer has to be a whole number because I am only using multiply , add  and subtract.Also I have changed the random numbers so they don't go in negative.(It is supposed to be for a primary school).I said line 6 sorry you explained line 7....

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Also I've amended my answer.

Comment: OMG !!! You are a Genius ;) You explained it such a good way , I completely understand why we use eval and result now.Can I give points or reputations ? I am new :) I pressed the up arrow and the tick.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) says:

> eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
>
> The `expression` argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python
> expression

In short, the string argument passed to `eval()` is executed as normal Python instructions. For example:

```
hello_printer = 'print("hello")'
eval(hello_printer)
```

prints out `hello` onto screen, as would be done when executing the `print("hello")` instruction. The Python interpreter simply tries and executes the string argument passed to the `eval` function.

The argument to your eval function is `str(number1)+oper+str(number2)`, which is broken down to:

- convert `number1` to string form
- concatenate the operator to `number1` which is a string form
- convert the `number2` to string form and concatenate it to the previous

E.g., if `number1` is `10`, `oper` is `+`, and `number2` is `20`, then this makes the string `'10+20'`, which is passed to the `eval` function and evaluated as `10+20`. Then the evaluated value is stored in the variable `result`. Finally, `result` is compared to the answer provided by the user. If they match, `True` is stored in the answer, otherwise `False`, which is then checked to give the output of 'correct' or 'incorrect'.

Comment: So eval() is useless in a way ?

Comment: Not at all. Using eval() you can execute dynamically created python code. Read the documentation to know more about eval()